# how to replace the old selector content in angular 4 or redirect it to full new page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I have an index page in Angular 4 and after the login, I want to replace the old page content or at least redirect it to the dashboard. On the index page there is something like about us and in the dashboard there is custom.

I already tried I think every thing on the internet like:

```
{ path: '', redirect To: '/dashboard', path Match: 'full' }
defaulter
```

Comment: You can implement routing to route to your other components. See the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: i already try that it just replace the the selector with html code what i need is to replace root selector not just child selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can "replace" the root selector. Rather you can change it to *only* contain a router outlet:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then anything you route to this router outlet can use the full page and replace any menu/navigation components.

You can then have something like a shell component that has the desired menu.

**shell.component.html**

```
<mh-menu></mh-menu>

<div class='container'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

You could then replace this shell component with any other component with its own menu.

I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Here is a picture showing the app's router outlet and a shell component's router outlet:

[image]

Comment: i tried that too but intstead of  <router-outlet><div class=""></div></router-outlet> it just place it after it: <router-outlet></router-outlet><div class=""></div>

Comment: Maybe your routes are not configured correctly. Did you look at the github link I provided? Check out the route configurations there.